# Performance counter in WCF

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, performancecounter

I am looking for some concrete example of performance counter usages to measure WCF application performance measurement.

We already have WCF service hosted on IIS in Production environment. 
I want to update the code/config to enable performance counter to capture service performance and save the performance data in some file. Since I want to measure the performance from PDN server, I have to save data into some file (like perfmon file).

This file will be used, later point of time, to check the performance and for decision making if any changes are required in WCF service (e.g. serviceThrottling etc.) or server machine itself (like hardware upgrade etc).

I know we can enable performance counter by

```
<diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
```

But this will only for real time. Data will not be available for future analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user-defined Data Collector Set to log performance counters data.
Data Collector Set generates a log file which can be used for future analysis.